# TypeError: res is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

```
exports.signup_submit = function(req,res){ 
    console.log(req.body.username,"------------------"); 
    var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (username) VALUES (req.body.username)"; 
    con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) { 
        if (err) { 
            return res(err); 
        } else { 
            return res(result); 
        } 
        res.render(__dirname + '/views/success.html');    
});
```

Comment: correct, res is not a function

Answer (score 0):

res is the object response and it contains the lots of tools and data for the response that you gonna close after finishing with it.

check the node API [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

replace `res()` with `res.end()`

or render :

```js
exports.signup_submit = function(req,res){ 
  console.log(req.body.username,"------------------"); 
  var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (username) VALUES (req.body.username)"; 
  con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) { 
       if (err) { 
         return res.render(__dirname + '/views/error.html'); 
        }

       res.render(__dirname + '/views/success.html');    
    });
```

Comment: Why return a value from a query result callback?

Comment: you can do whatever you want, but remember there is no need to handle error first callback with if-else you can instead just if for the error and return.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "res.send" or "res.render"
if you have special place for your errors on template, you can use "res.render(path_to_template, error)"

You can read more about it [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res)